# Split from 40900000 to 409-00-000

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Does anybody knows a way to convert "40900000" to "409-00-000" with single command, sed or awk.
I already tried couple of ways with sed but no luck at all. I need to do this in a bulk, there is around 40k line and some of this lines are not proper, so they need to be fixed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to run external commands, `bash` or `ksh` can do it themselves.

```
$ a=12345678
$ [ ${#a} = 8 ] && { b=${a:0:3}-${a:3:2}-${a:5};a=$b;}
$ echo $a
123-45-678
$ a=abc-de-fgh
$ [ ${#a} = 8 ] && { b=${a:0:3}-${a:3:2}-${a:5};a=$b;}
$ echo $a
abc-de-fgh
```

Comment: This will fail if number are already formatted. `409-00-000`  Some are ok, some not.

Comment: Answer updated. It isn't obvious from the question the OP is also looking for the filtering part.

Comment: I do not have filtering actually, and also it is not certain that all lines are 8 character numbers, plus may be some of them can be already formatted with 3-2-3 style. So purpose is to find none formatted 8 digit numeric lines and format it.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU sed, I would do it like this:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/\1-\2-\3/' filename
# or, equivalently
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/\1-\2-\3/' filename
```

- The `-r` or `-E` enables *extended regex mode*, which avoids the need to escape all the parentheses
- `\1` is the first capture group (the bits in between the `( )`)
- `[0-9]` means the range zero to nine
- `{3}` means three of the preceeding character or range

**edit**: Thanks for all the comments.

On other systems that lack the `-r` switch, or its alias `-E`, you have to escape the `( )` and `{ }` above. That leaves you with:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1-\2-\3/' filename
```

At the expense of repetition, you can avoid some of the escapes by simply repeating the `[0-9]`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1-\2-\3/' filename
```

For the record, Perl is equally capable of doing this sort of thing:

```
perl -pwe 's/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{3})/$1-$2-$3/' filename
```

- `-p` means print
- `-w` means enable warnings
- `-e` means execute one line
- `\d` is the "digit" character class (zero to nine)

Comment: Note that the `-r` switch is somewhat non-standard - it's not available on BSD, Mac OS X, *et al*.

Comment: @PaulR thanks. It looks like you can't use the `{3}` either without that switch. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can use `-E` to enable extended regex which supports `{3}` etc, so `sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/\1-\2-\3/'` works, and should be fairly portable.

Comment: It can be done with out the switch, like so: `sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1-\2-\3/'` . @PaulR: `-E` only works with BSD sed and with GNU sed as an undocumented feature as an alias for `-r`..

Comment: @Scrutinizer thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer. Hopefully it includes everything now!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`, like this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

or more succinctly, with extended regex syntax:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/\1-\2-\3/'
```

Answer (score 1):

For `golfing`:

```
$ echo "40900000" | awk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS='3 2 3' OFS='-' 
409-00-000
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\(...\)\(..\)\(...\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

The dot matches character, and the surrounding with `\(` and `\)` makes it a group. The `\1` references the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, an `awk`

```
echo "40900000" | awk '{a=$0+0} length(a)==8 {$0=substr(a,1,3)"-"substr(a,4,2)"-"substr(a,6)}1'
409-00-000
```

This test if there are 8 digits.

---

A more complex version (need gnu awk due to gensub):

```
echo "40900000" | awk --re-interval '{print gensub(/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","g")}'
409-00-000
```

```
echo "409-00-000" | awk --re-interval '{print gensub(/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","g")}'
409-00-000
```

Answer (score 0):

Turnarround from STDIN:

```
echo "40900000" | grep -E "[0-9]{8}" | cut -c "1-3,4-5,6-8" --output-delimiter=-
```

from file:

```
grep -E "[0-9]{8}" filename | cut -c "1-3,4-5,6-8" --output-delimiter=-
```

But I prefect Tom Fenech's solution.